# Enabling dependency injection in a mechanism other than the default ones in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

I have a mechanism in my Symfony application where I need to enable dependency injection based on the default service container. I found the code in the `HttpKernel` where dependency injection is managed throughout the controllers mechanism [here (browse on Sourcegraph)](https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/symfony/symfony@dbe37de8207811aca5c0fefc4c415817454cb3ff/-/blob/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php#L132-142).

I am not sure however how I can instantiate the `ArgumentResolver` to use for this purpose.

Below is what I've tried so far:

```php
class DataSourceController
{
  public function queryDatasource(string $hash, Request $request, ArgumentResolverInterface $argument_resolver)
  {
    // Logic to construct the $datasource variable

    $arguments = $argument_resolver->getArguments($request, [$datasource, 'query']);

    $data = $datasource->query(...$arguments);

    return new JsonResponse($data);
  }
}
```

However, it appears that `ArgumentResolverInterface` cannot be auto-wired and I am not sure how I should proceed about this. So how can I instantiate a subclass of `ArgumentResolverInterface`, or what other mechanism should I use to achieve dependency injection in an arbitrary component of my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little more research and scanning the sources of Symfony, I was able to come with a solution that suits my needs: I manually create an instance of `ArgumentResolver` and use it.

**NOTE** That my use case requires resolving an object that is not a service, so it cannot be resolved by the dependency injection mechanism like any other service. I included that in my answer as it might be useful to others:

```php
$resolvers = [];
array_push($resolvers, ...ArgumentResolver::getDefaultArgumentValueResolvers());
array_push($resolvers, new class implements ArgumentValueResolverInterface {
  // implement the interface to resolve an argument with a specific type/name
});

$argument_resolver = new ArgumentResolver(new ArgumentMetadataFactory(), $resolvers);

// to use it:

$arguments = $argument_resolver->getArguments($request, [$datasource, 'query']);
$datasource->query(...$arguments);
```

I hope this will be of use to others.

---

<sup>I cannot certify this as THE solution, or THE BEST solution, but it's what seems to work for my use case. I welcome others to comment/answer so we can improve the solution together</sup>